# Width of the parent container with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I set "DOP_ThumbnailGallery_Container" to have the width of the parent container

```
$('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_Container', Container).width($(Container).width());
```

I tried this way /\  but it doesn't work, it gives the width of the **window**;

I even tried to have the outer container with overflow hidden, but it breaks it!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Or something like ...

http://jsfiddle.net/y3597/2/

```
$('#object').width($('#object').parent().width());
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the parents function of jquery?

You can do something like this:

```
$('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_Container').width($('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_Container').parents("div").width());
```

source: http://api.jquery.com/parents/