# Google Pie Chart with Width of Parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-visualization

I'm using `bootstrap3`, looked at [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) assuming I have something like below:

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="well">
         <header>Genel İstatistik</header>
         <content id="general"></content>
         <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want my chart to have width of my div and auto resize height by width, in this case, width is defined by `col-*-4` rule. How to make width 100% to parent at `options`?

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erayerdin/qfL1or3L/).

Comment: Copy your code here and post the link https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: updated, added fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it seems there is no built-in way to define width of *Google Pie Chart* responsively. However, I figured a way out, so there it is. According to the documentation on Google, passing an example `options` variable to `.draw()` function will define the size, the `options` as below:

```
var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
               'width':400,
               'height':300};
```

So, all I have to do is get the width of `document` and do some simple maths, like:

```
var width = $(document).width();

var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
               'width':width/3,
               'height':300};
```

`width/3` is fine for me, but you might want to take the parent's width then apply. In this case, you might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992173/2926992).

Comment: to make chart responsive, listen for `'resize'` on `window`, set chart options, redraw chart --> [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32523331/5090771)